# Mount windows 7 boot partition via. arch linux

Tags: arch-linux

I was just installing arch linux on my pc, besides windows 7.
Accidentally I unmounted the boot partition of windows and tried to mount it again with the command "mount /dev/sda1 /mnt" (sda1 = windows boot partition)
and as i tried to boot windows it said "Missing operating system".

Is it possible to remount the windows partition, and if yes, how?